# Linux Development/Deployment for Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: java, android, linux, eclipse

I'm using a Linux system (Xubuntu) to develop an Android app. I am using Eclipse to develop this app. I would like to be able to test on my Samsung Galaxy S3, but Eclipse cannot seem to find my device. There is nothing listed under the "Choose a running Android device" section.

I searched Samsung's website for USB drivers to the Galaxy S3, but I found none for Linux - only Windows and Mac. Where's the love for us Linux users? It seems absurd that there would be no USB driver for a Linux system to communicate with a Linux-based device. Is there a driver that I can use?

Comment: You do not need a uSB driver on Linux, your problem is situated somewhere else.

Comment: linux doesn't require drivers. Did you make sure that USB debugging is On?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try

> adb kill-server
>
> adb start-server

It is required to do the above in Linux.  And also you should be logged in as root user,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3129903/603744

Or if by any chance you haven't seen this question ,

[Samsung Galaxy 7" (GT-P6210) not detecting for USB debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8668923/603744)

Comment: Thanks, this worked great! I don't need to be root for it to be working, however.

Comment: wow. That's cool. I have logged in as root all the time so far without knowing this. Cool man..

Comment: Any adb command would work. You don't need to explicitly kill or start the server. Running "adb devices" or "adb install /path/to/apk" will automatically start adb if it's not already running.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need usb driver for linux, Follow instruction from [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html). You need to add a file to rules.d

Comment: Following the instruction from the android developers side worked for me. In addition I had to enable the developer mode on my device. This is sort of weird since Android 4.2 .

Answer (score 2):

USB Drivers aren't required for Linux, which is why you can't find them.

To be able to deploy your application to your S3, you need to enable USB Debugging mode.

Home Screen -> Apps -> Settings -> Choose Developer options -> USB debugging

Home Screen -> Apps -> Settings -> Security -> Disable debug mode (turn this off)

Now connect your phone, and then run this command:

```
adb devices
```

It should list your device. Also, your Android notification area should show that debugging mode is enabled.

You'll now be able to deploy applications to it.

Answer (score 0):

I also work on Ubuntu. You will have to set the USB Vendor IDs. Take a look on this [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html)