# ADB on boot no devices

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, adb

I have this linux pc permanently connected to Android Device. I need to start adb server on boot with rc.local. but the problem is it wont find my devices then.

When i reboot pc the adb start-server is started but then when i come to pc it will display:

```
List of devices attached
-
```

when i manualy then run adb kill-server ; adb start-server i get normal list

```
List of devices attached 
xxx device
```

I have udev rule set to:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2207", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

and my rc.local is:

```
/opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb start-server
```

I've tried the init.d way:

```
#!/bin/sh
case "$1" in
start)
    # Start daemon.
    echo -n "Starting ADB: "
    /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb start-server
    ;;
stop)
    # Stop daemons.
    echo -n "Shutting ADB: "
    /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb kill-server
    ;;
restart)
    $0 stop
    $0 start
    ;;
*)
    echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"
    exit 1
esac

exit 0
```

but it all ended the same. No devices after boot

Comment: try this as admin user http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127539/ubuntu-android-device-debug/3129903

Comment: add `udevadm trigger --action=add --attr-match=idVendor=2207` after your `adb start-server`

Comment: this did not help. Still no devices until i manualy kill-server. I think rc.local cannot find my /.android/adb_usb.ini file